# Efficient table-lookup computation

Tags: atomic-code-golf

The challenge: compute the day of the week from a `MM-DD` representation of a day in this year (2021).

However, you have to write your program in the following subset of Python: (*I chose Python because it's popular and easy to understand even to the people who doesn't know the language. Obviously you can use another program in another language to generate the program, and you're encouraged to post the source code of that program*)

```python
# This is the input. For example this represents the date 2021-01-28.
m1 = "0"
m2 = "1"
d1 = "2"
d2 = "8"


T = {
# `T` is a dict
# * each key must be a string of digits [0-9]
# * each value must be a single digit.
"1234": "1",
"5678": "2",
}

# The main program code.
# Each line must have the format:
# <variable_name> = T[<string formed by concatenating string literals or other variables>]
# Example:
variable_1 = T["12" + m1 + "3" + "4"]
output = T[variable_1]

# This must be exactly one `print` statement like this at the end of the program
print(output)
```

*Background: This is basically the only way [Preproc](https://tio.run/#preproc) (the C/C++ preprocessor) can parse tokens. [See how Boost's `BOOST_PP_INC_I` macro is implemented](https://github.com/boostorg/preprocessor/blob/aa8f347df2b189b14c4079c6fb7fa2819ac4a6f1/include/boost/preprocessor/arithmetic/inc.hpp#L31).*

More info:

- You can (and should!) submit multiple programs in one answer if the method that you use to generate these programs are similar.
- You can reassign variables, but doing that will not make your score better (than labeling each usage of the variables `a_1, a_2, a_3, ...`.
- To be clear (this is implied by the rules), you're not allowed to do `x = "0"` or `x = y + z`; only `x = T[...]` is allowed.
- The output should be `0` if the day is Monday, `1` if the day is Tuesday, ..., `6` if the day is Sunday.
- The program must not raise an error given valid input data.

#### Winning criteria

Let `A` about the number of entries in the dict `T`, and `B` be the number of assignment instructions (excluding the input assignment instructions to `m1, m2, d1, d2` but including the final assignment to `output`).

You should minimize both `A` and `B`.

Note that you can make the length of the keys of the dict `T` arbitrarily long and it doesn't make the score worse; however it doesn't make the score better either.

Because there isn't a consensus on whether it's allowed to have 2 separate winning criteria, the method to calculate the score is described in [this meta answer ("**Solution 2**")](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20720/69850), with the board size `10000 10000`. -- For example, if you have a program with `A=100` and `B=100`, enter into the input of the [score calculation program](https://tio.run/##hVFNb4MwDD2XX@FxCm2KQLuhpj9iV5ZDEGmJBgElVJRfz@zQL2nTxoE49vN7z84wj01v35fFdEPvRnCag589BzNqN/Z966PWWO1FucV06sfaWBk1HCbRqYEZO3LsSU/G1qptmYs/613MIfSUmUySaHAIYtRxj/Hs8UROGZ16F8Bg7K0pL2QRbRSH6l8FZN@slATHi/IeXYM6ZqBsDdUxQ0DQStUwaFuzkpDy7iD1ODP70rNoVVfVCq4FXMl28GXIlFP2rFmOgtqytStJClij0sgyl6Iz99Ka4I/yPqf7c2DS4kB43G@HJQhCGJPW2fWXIUlCLgBDgiqP10hDqppvehx@MQ/mROmDaORTOGwoMFNEnGuJwNVBTDKKnPaXdhTNdvp7/F2e4Aut6L1gL6NnkujMm3hBg269hgab9q9bQZ9bNu3y/Y9VhQeNPwJ9EdPjU5QsS57hB@Ef5Wv0DQ)

```
10000 10000
100 100
```

and the calculated result is 1970199.

#### Recommended header format

```
## Score: (5, 1), (4, 2), (3, 3) -> 999, Combined score: 999, Combined score improvement: 99
```

- Score: The (A, B) parameters of your generated program(s), and (optionally) the computed score of all your generated programs.
- Combined score: the computed score of all the generated programs of the whole community (all answers posted so far)  (you can easily calculate the "combined score" by taking the most recent/best combined score answer, then modify the score-list to add your program's scores. Also you should add a link to the score calculation program with your generated programs' scores as input)
- Combined score improvement: the difference between the most-recent computed score and the current combined score.

This is not a requirement, but just in case someone want to write a visualization/leaderboard script. (I intend to have it like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57038635#57038635))

#### [Table of all values](https://tio.run/##VY1BDoIwEEX3nGLCqo1IoK5g4c4ruG9kkEZpm2GMEsLZa4sxxr@Zv3j/jZ95cPYQghm9I4ZOM7IZMesdwegsD2AskLZXFHUBtdrVss0ghmn@lJREd3r@Y5tG/oAUT8ay6PNl87aVWpe4SRf2R1i@r8tUhKpUdGxkkdSyfCLeYhFyzeXmxdcFPcNZ3x94InLUgtfTlIXwBg)

#### [Program to verify submissions](https://tio.run/##ZVHLboMwEDzjr3B8slVEgnsKkk9V@wVVL1UVIbwkVgJGxmmDEN9OvTwUNb0wq92Z2WXcdP5k6@dxLKyGVjHGyLvqyUDs1TdXr3RKtg8dSZBFTNVY56nOPXhTAdFQ0m9wpuy4qQPxgJOYoq/ISAS3BgoP@rDYtN7xVZtgweVOpjGtbO1PcbDtRPIDcA4FF4JEFc5kGATUUt1XkGh2PGhTeGPr3HUKS16lahapWacWqZYCz4GC420x/ScXq6X6N/pkc4t9kciUi3SjHn4uo40ztecle8vNBXRGp3NVf796WPeqfsbQeIyof2gMTBBSWjdlGiwnbJO2uRjP2ZZhzOvilxMUZ1MfZ26P340bkiQJHhF6TDmjicvrI/AQTSqfUrSIvOsQJlqI/w9pvxfZ@swl6yeXbCeHPhAR2fLiQQ@3AhpPP/LLFV6dsy7EkrctGcdf)

Note that this program does not verify that the provided program is inside the subset, only if the output is valid.

Comment: Sandbox link: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20687/69850

Comment: As you can see there's a trivial (365, 1) solution, but what should I do with it?

Comment: I think you can post it as community wiki (or let someone else post it).

Comment: A=20?? I can't see how to encode the months in less than 12, and you still need to do something about the days, which is at least another 10... and then you need to combine the months and days... suffice it to say that my best A so far is 52, but given my B is now 43, that's not very helpful.

Comment: (I created a separate chat room for the challenge: [Efficient table-lookup computation -- discussion room | chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119758/efficient-table-lookup-computation-discussion-room))

Answer (score 4):

## Score: 679685 (`A=64`, `B=6`)

```python
T = {
    # three digits: first day of the month, 0-based (12 entries)
    "001": "4", "002": "0", "003": "0", "004": "3", "005": "5", "006": "1", "007": "3", "008": "6", "009": "2", "010": "4", "011": "0", "012": "2", 
    # two digits ab: lookup table for (a + b) % 7 (52 entries)
    "00": "0", "01": "1", "02": "2", "03": "3", "04": "4", "05": "5", "06": "6", 
    "10": "1", "11": "2", "12": "3", "13": "4", "14": "5", "15": "6", "16": "0", 
    "20": "2", "21": "3", "22": "4", "23": "5", "24": "6", "25": "0", "26": "1", 
    "30": "3", "31": "4", "32": "5", "33": "6", "34": "0", "35": "1", "36": "2", 
    "40": "4", "41": "5", "42": "6", "43": "0", "44": "1", "45": "2", "46": "3", 
    "50": "5", "51": "6", "52": "0", "53": "1", "54": "2", "55": "3", "56": "4", 
    "60": "6", "61": "0", "62": "1", "63": "2", "64": "3", "65": "4", "66": "5", "67": "6", "68": "0", "69": "1", 
}

# (d2 + 6) % 7 = (d2 - 1) % 7
d2_0d1 = T["6" + d2]

# (d2 - 1 + 1*d1) % 7
d2_1d1 = T[d1 + d2_0d1]

# (d2 - 1 + 2*d1) % 7
d2_2d1 = T[d1 + d2_1d1]

# (d2 - 1 + 3*d1) % 7 = (d2 - 1 + 10*d1) % 7 = (d1d2 - 1) % 7
day_of_month = T[d1 + d2_2d1]

month_start = T["0" + m1 + m2]

output = T[month_start + day_of_month]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZTdbqMwEIXv8xQjqkpkQyTP@CdtpL5F71YVIoI0aAtE4KiKVvvsWf@UMWlzdTCHj3PsCeerPQ29vHVYQEcFlAXUTtYEL9D254vN17dXp/@uwP0ewJ7GpoG6fW/ttIdjO04W6uoKw9HdaqAbensqQGwP1dTUkCNB09uxbaZ1AGRCYLaHTGWF1@S1iFoutPJaRq291lEbrzHq3cLz5LWJ@tlrChpFehdi4iPNnrnV5/DVCarDHj6G4c/lDLY6fDRwHEbIK9jAYQ2PsINc/@y0QKeElILIlFWlSItmZi4QiTF4wMTcARNjBwxKxqBiDGreBzRzpkgkwRhCxhAxhiRjSDGGNFcj3vxIlIIxMp2pJMZIyRipGCM1V5Pm7hgylY5LIWMUMUalGVGKMUpzNWXmTJGoBWM0MkansdOSMVoxRmuups2cKRKNYIxJE2WIMUYyxqQxNpqrGcOZzC7BnhLsmTf632r1ALn7M27AxOl7CZdbwHC5qqkUNbrV19@O42w1vc3POJNbwF918uKXt8Zg9c9@s9PSTt/s@MMuZ3sK5t8p7pbxLnF1LYdjGT4Ud3AK8LBeTrYabWwlfKvOezpfbbhY91EKt5bWDSy5b7fz2PY2j@b1TeBW4H8) and try the [Generator / Testing program!](https://tio.run/##jVRNj9owEL3nV0yzqpIsASWhZSWkHLrnPXLbriKDHTCbL9mmLYry2@nY@SBhOcAJv3nv2fM0k@qsDmWxvFx4XpVCwY5krKBEWN1ZnqVlvb1CDM7vwoEZOOA8/7A2CNSNZVWi3AuS67KBNOPt9YrPsPAE6iAYA8r3XMk1pFxIBZScoUyxxCAvC3XwIZhviWQU3DACVijBmfQ6v7QULQt4AYIUe@aGPoRLb20B/oxjgo4@JPiKvoeFkbT0KIhQYQDPaD7ZGampE9QGXAdR45jCH5KdGJakEu5g3Go276j6wJrhGGjUaOrYNdYbew12bRiN7YMzCeNONn/LLhkg2zVkZfl5qkCRbcZAt@0SjGDrwXd4Affn3WT4NZWXPhGEj6OwAuAp8DheAcskg542DqLmTX3sMrjNweWzo3mCN5TvZPFgHje0cSRxX1hg7oJXLk6bp4eumcboOHh@ApdGWFy14cTmOIfQHC0aJQENEd282ysbaTT66DVIQiB8pldu2HFpaKhae0OPxvTohh5@oS97@vVh@s5gAoeTF5NzUqZJO@dj88iYGzyRiuBWmq4C3VWuOblurTyp6tSWxtQZjH0/THKPr1NxyrdMaDke5aO7pf31fg/uU5vR8OET90z1UzZcPNMrN523XF8R4YL7QPEvBmeGdljeea11YbvHg4r9Yzu3GxzvChMpGWbTRxZ37/C1Yws28A0/Zy3cmIZuruouqgQvlOv8yjJQTOISV9qbOmjFMxbj53MhFWVCeB0V43M3Hu4B5TvFy4KIc7/T90Sdqm/hcvkP)

Answer (score 4):

## Combined score: [440654](https://tio.run/##hVFNb4MwDD0vv8LrKbQpgrXrJNTsR@zKcggiHdEgoISq7a/v7LB@SJs2DsSxn997dobT2PRudT7bbuj9CN4ICKcgwI7Gj33fBtZaZ4Is55hOw1hbp1gj4CA7PXDrRoE96c66Wrct97P3ejETEHvKTCUJGzyCOHVcYjx7PJFTsV3vIxis@27KC1WwBy2g@lcB2R8mSoLjRYeArkG/ZqBdDdVrhoColephMK7mJSHVxUEacGb@aU6y1V1VazgWcCTb0ZclU167D8NzFDSOT11JUsAUlVaVuZKdvZSmhLiWlzndbwOTlgDC4347LEEUwpi0Pny/H5Ik5iIwJqhyfY00pqrTt56AX8yD3VF6Kxt1E44biswUEedUInC1lQfFmDdh346ymR/@Hn@RJ/hCE3op@d3omSI6@yjv0GDaYKDBpuX9VtDnnB8W@fLHquKDzt4ifTGjx6coOZ/zDD@If7ZZwZo9Z7B6YesNrFds/QTPT18) (63, 4), (50, 37), (46, 43), (42, 52)

### First program: A=<s>64</s> 63, B=4

```python
T = {
    # 0mm: lookup table for a such that a1 % 7 is the first day of the month
    "001": "1", "002": "2", "003": "2", "004": "3", "005": "6", "006": "0", "007": "3", "008": "4", "009": "5", "010": "1", "011": "2", "012": "5", 
    # ab0: lookup table for ab % 7, "010" already happens to be the correct answer "1"
    "000": "0", "020": "2", "030": "3", "040": "4", "050": "5", "060": "6", "070": "0", "080": "1", "090": "2", 
    "100": "3", "110": "4", "120": "5", "130": "6", "140": "0", "150": "1", "160": "2", 
    "200": "6", "210": "0", "220": "1", "230": "2", "240": "3", "250": "4", "260": "5", 
    "300": "2", "310": "3", "320": "4", "330": "5", "340": "6", "350": "0", "360": "1", 
    "400": "5", "410": "6", "420": "0", "430": "1", "440": "2", "450": "3", "460": "4", 
    "500": "1", "510": "2", "520": "3", "530": "4", "540": "5", "550": "6", "560": "0", 
    "600": "4", "610": "5", "620": "6", "630": "0", "640": "1", "650": "2", "660": "3", 
}

m = T["0" + m1 + m2]
d3 = T["0" + d2 + "0"]
d = T[d1 + d3 + "0"]
output = T[m + d + "0"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZTdattAEIXv9RSDSiEhLszM/jgJ5C1yV0pZWwoysX6QZYIpfXZ3V@voqKW6EEeze85@RyANl6npO3NtZUOtbujnhqooK6UXOnTDebq7v75G/augeH0hbttnOvb9@3mgKeyONb31IwU6nfcNTU2YKAh9pS0dTvExrh7G00RVuFD/Ng/avpuaOaxklvKZSik3SWvSmrVZaZu0ydol7bP2SXPW29Wex6Rt1k9Ju1kL4ywR5It@7rk1DDv@X8NdanULonAc61BdqAnDUHexaU@7eq6378ex3se30J0@6jEd@NmVwauM8w2D3TLYHYPdM3pvVzmPq05PS2Y@UBjBIggWRbAYBItFsDgEi/8nWBkmFZhUYVKDhmoBog4g6vmvN18ahskITEZhMgb0xgLEOIAYv4DkYMswWYHJKkzWgN5agFgHEOsXkBzsGCYnMDmFyRnQOwsQ5wDi/AKSgz3D5AUmrzB5A3pvAeIdQLxfQIrfRdHGD/n1e7TQA7WSbvqjqMxqGr/7h5QZx/O0SrvijtuwP0/xlzCvtGnhNr8O46Gb7vLq/ZXlG8sf) Verification: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTbbtpAEH3GX7HZqpKtILr3BCQ/Ve0XRH2JqsjYS7CCL1ovTRDi2@mOFxhKyoP3MDPnzJmxvP3Or7tWHsuuskNOKT0@kZzsExJ@XwhrmgXZdN3btie@WG4sWXWOFGTYlmvi14UnBSdfyQOph/A3ZGs3eFIVO9KtxkDTtX49ilHGOF0QyukUsAAsIpZXWAGWEWvAJmIDmEX8cFXzCFhFPAesR8wZ9uIc9bk415wmLJbsfxMuYaqTECk2zhbVjqyLvrdtmLQjSzuOV3bO2TJsoR3erYOG51kZ@hUM@0uG3hVD75qhd8Nw7ocrncermeYXzdiQMxTmHIW5QGEuUZgrFOYahbm5ERYMSYIjSQgkCYkTCoVGhEYjwrB/Nk8lQ5LkSJICSVKie6nQiNRoRJqLkSisGJIUR5ISSFIS3SuFRpRGI8pcjERhzZCkOZK0QJKW6F4rNKI1GtHmYiQKG4Ykw5FkBJKMRPdGoRGj0YgxFyPJIUma8CE/PQcKuScNh4f4nVTyKlqJ8AgwhMdoBVWh4hTstr7f@jHTQOIUP4ZbIknqpu8cfOve@rqxSWVX5I919WqX1m2gvUBmSuBeyRbJxH704UOx1UsUzQfv0jN3BiAVTPBpvDCmcIVks3dr3wJIsyyZNJATIRHOSuTYIplExZeqLn3dtYXb5QDThueRlEdefqJWIgM7tkzB25R8omdnyfxT6pnGUFjOpF6dqHf5zXAL0ru69emK/izqja0WZLSb79H14dw338czBG5XtL8JHGiWJHA7ge8gOZ7DbOg3tU/pNwprPjf@vrblW92@xto9PO/cYTabBY0JaIx7BhFXtK82Davh4p6DxMS7HRxjGVzl10XzebY4v@YV3Y8qCyYO@1AIJz298cC3H6XtPflVbLb2h3OdC2sphuH4Fw) Edit: Reduced A by 1 thanks to a hint from @user202729.

### Second program: A=<s>56</s> <s>52</s> 50, B=37

```python
T = {
    # 0th day of the month (12 entries)
    "01": "3", "02": "6", "03": "6", "04": "2", "05": "4", "06": "0", "07": "2", "08": "5", "09": "1", "10": "3", "11": "6", "12": "1", 
    # abcde: (a%7%2^b^c)+d+e%7>>1 (30 entries) e.g. a0001: a%7%2 abc01: a^b^c 00cde: c+d+e>>1 0000e: e%7>>1
    "01001": "1", "01101": "0", "10001": "1", "10101": "0", "11001": "0", "11101": "1", 
    "20001": "0", "30001": "1", "40001": "0", "50001": "1", "60001": "0", "70001": "0", "80001": "1", "90001": "0", 
    "00000": "0", "00001": "0", "00010": "0", "00011": "1", "00100": "0", "00101": "1", "00110": "1", "00111": "1", 
    "00002": "1", "00003": "1", "00004": "2", "00005": "2", "00006": "3", "00007": "0", "00008": "0", "00009": "1", 
    # Convert from binary (modulo 7) (8 entries)
    "000": "0", "001": "1", "010": "2", "011": "3", "100": "4", "101": "5", "110": "6", "111": "0", 
}

# Get the day of the month and convert it to binary.
m = T[m1 + m2]
mh = T["0000" + m]
m0 = T[m + "0001"]
m1 = T[mh + "0001"]
m2 = T["0000" + mh]

# Convert the ones day digit (modulo 7) to binary.
d2h = T["0000" + d2]
d20 = T[d2 + "0001"]
d21 = T[d2h + "0001"]
d22 = T["0000" + d2h]

# Convert the tens day digit to binary.
d10 = T[d1 + "0001"]
d11 = T["0000" + d1]

# Multiply by three (modulo 7)
o = T["000" + d10 + d11]
o1 = T[d10 + d11 + "001"]
o0 = T[o + d10 + "001"]
o1 = T[o + o1 + "001"]
o2 = T[o + d11 + "001"]

# Add the ones.
c0 = T["000" + o0 + d20]
o0 = T[o0 + d20 + "001"]
c1 = T["00" + c0 + o1 + d21]
o1 = T[c0 + o1 + d21 + "01"]
o3 = T["00" + c1 + o2 + d22]
o2 = T[c1 + o2 + d22 + "01"]

# Add the month offset.
c0 = T["000" + o0 + m0]
o0 = T[o0 + m0 + "001"]
c1 = T["00" + c0 + o1 + m1]
o1 = T[c0 + o1 + m1 + "01"]
c2 = T["00" + c1 + o2 + m2]
o2 = T[c1 + o2 + m2 + "01"]
o4 = T["000" + o3 + c2]
o3 = T[o3 + c2 + "001"]

# Reduce modulo 7.
c0 = T["000" + o0 + o3]
c1 = T["00" + c0 + o1 + o4]
o1 = T[c0 + o1 + o4 + "01"]
c2 = T["000" + c1 + o2]
o2 = T[c1 + o2 + "001"]
o0 = T[o0 + o3 + c2 + "01"]

# Convert from binary.
output = T[o2 + o1 + o0]
```

Verification: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVbdi9s4EH@O/wrVZcFmg09Ssskm4MJRevfUl1LupWwXryVvTGMr2Mq1IeRv385I/pCcHJwf4vn6zfxmRjI5nPRO1Yu3XAnZpmEYvn0lKTkHBJ73hOodEdmJqILonSSVqsEQMU5krZtStrGJCykLtyRchHMQOYorIy5GcYkiN@IDiksjrlCkRlyPAY8oPhhxgyJDkdGhBGNDXsb7gI5w9pILuSVRdre@499fvufxvbiXd@sPHxiJFnTgTWTympCMUsq2xAQj1CiIIpSaPDmiEQuBFHSbqWsan7EBTOVqzPNZzsxqzMMx6vksbtCY12CIWCecMacoo66PUc/HqKc5RcduuFOZ2u0NmrNAeB48bTVuH561N5NHT9v4Rbk3tIXHf@n5HjzfyvOtPe3Ri9y4vu6MfFT1v7LRpGhURV7KOmtOJKqUOO4VWcckepyebn9dzvTpOAY2XoFuvctuC8Np7la76jYwsLoEwXvyt9Tmil3dtqwWJO8YlxCjOspJUMFF/fqtYuSeVPwpqHZGN3MO0QYmakNAM4cwBBOzpp1r4xPk7gkp9XNCLqqWreEmyldg4YzLIST4hIIAWoJbEoI7FQVnnXHnWfkUf81Ey9pl4pZnXSXm5mRskpOZlJ@Pe10e9ifycoK0jZROT4EaIBZBzS8AVUe7t9hCWEfZ2mqI7@1ssCs3nDvhjh2Y/SnEMPIkyKnHRZnCnI4FO8OYIh8aRkBO@8ow84GOZzVQQ2rhIdGhuInhA2PPOiAd2vbUqqJopb5Nv5qwr/4H@eoW92qknvPb1KtbzKuRuFr6/BaI5sMoOt3bzxcpjjn2aU/L7R7V4r97UcsbvQCR617cZm70MTl6dGzAXcyNz10SqKM@HLXF8YEDfXqDfwBBUFYHBQiRaanLSgZCFgRylMUpKmvAPaNnTvA/Q7wNZvLXQeZaimebNW11E/XYBIWIU87m9mjM8fLGyU8pf4AQxXEwq9DHwQFvwdOxRDCzGZ9FmetSIfUUxahiqQWlFpd2UMFjpCPzCLnNyRU87lOmV65voTXB1GZl0UHfpZPmtuTQlLWOivCvrNxLsSWGbnoeWV/6uunZvsEwHdF5YriEcRAUqjEzhZTm3SbtYV/qKPwjxDH3hT/uZP6jrF9t7Bl/3zWXJEkgxwxz2CsISZqsfpURjIbxe4YpZro54cuE4UfUDdps4m2/5iI8myxbyi9nCMR32G0c8PJXLg@a/JPtj/JT06gGxpK17dtv) Edit: Reduced A by <s>4</s> 6 thanks to a hint from @user202729.

Note that for the next two variants I used letters to code the lookup type for my sanity but obviously distinct digits work just as well.

### Third program: A=<s>52</s> <s>48</s> 46, B=43

Simply performs the XORs two bits at a time instead of three. Verification: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVZNb9s4ED1bv4JlEEBCDC1JO3ZsQAWKorunvRRFL0UaSCIVCzVFQ6a3NQz/9uzwQxItp0hzkGYe5@O9Ial4d9Qb1cxeSsXFPsMYv3xBGTpFCP5ukFwjojeI50ekKqQ3AknVABBThkSj21rsExuKJaF4jfAMT43NjL1w9iyw58Zmzr439tzZC2MTZy@DmAdj3zt7ZWxqbUqGXpQO9SnrYjz/vCj5GsX57fKWfS@Su/KO3y7fv6coZoteABLpc4pyQuga2UhIs/b3AhFboDCJJo0QAq6r4XQDQnryYNPAoeGK42n5w0KwQkm44nI6Z1ihJAijdOjT02BDInFD75xh6uDch86inyM4y1DHQ@isLsaKWShzFhKbhyv34coiXFmGzkMYtiIjZTeoWKOPqvlPtBpVrZKoqJu8PaJYKn7YKrRMUPwwOoxFuClFWL/wm8K8Mxzawm/K3Du0P3qF35SFdwaC5yi6Qf8IbW/G1SXJG45Kz7yGGOWpp5GEK/blG5YY3SFJzYM9RnLjUMPdQIAQi0jwzAHCgFCHbAKIXaZtHg2pbmKGjWrE3rLj9TPwCAYXUOLssj0HRpw5ApwN7TijHtuEIBslX7PQoglZhK2pb0ODipReVqS24L@Hra532yMqjlC0FSJQE6kuwyUQ@4Q85Rl3iO1imijXV/XhHqY9rIJgFgQPMJD6wHk/5zQqSUhD2Z6MDM080BcoO6EmvCRdU5jzwMQDY4ZDtIdnYSmDK2Yz2UDfA2NZQ/SVLHeYVVXthX5Vnhypk2@KkyNt8k1pJXtVmhwpk28KU/ML/jNTjvWj8344hs@CH0ozBXfMXp2Amv1WqppfSoX@fyo11Pp7PY6N5azI1dEmnUivRx307qBdgwJ3pRwz8vgC//@jqJY7BZeW51roWoqIiwrBNa6rY1w3kP1kVqbI/GJI1tFE/NqJUgv@5Gpne93GXW5qjJgRRqfuHE3NJyBJfwrxA4w4SaKJNGsMFuDNWTa0iCau4hOvS10r87HIjBlLmrmkzOVlPpWzxNARZWy4TdFVetKVzK6WvmEHwZAmdeVT32UjcWu0a@tGxxX@O6@3An4LWLrZaWB97vpmJ/cGYDyi0wg44ySKKtXamUJJ@96n@9221jH@C5sxd40/bkT5o26eXezJPN@15zRNocbE1HD3FYq0efMsYhgNZXfUlJjo9mheNsx8isOg1SpZd9tc4ZOtsibsfIJA88Z@xyFf/CrFTqOv@fYgPrWtamEs@X7/8j8)

### Fourth program: A=<s>48</s> <s>44</s> 42, B=52

Also performs the additions two bits at a time instead of three. Verification: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVbLbts4FF1bX8EqCCAhhoakHTsWoAKDojOrbopiNkUaSCQVCzVFQ6KnNQx/e8qXRFrxtF1MFuLh0X2ce0Qp3h/lVrSLFyIo64s4jl8@gQKcIqD@bgDPAZRbQMsjEDWQWwa4aBWRIAxYK7uG9akJjTlEcQ7iRTzXGGu8sngR4KXG2OJ7jZcWrzSGFq@DmAeN7y3eaIwMRtD3QsjXR3iIcfrLiuQgKW/Xt/hLld6R2/Xbtwgk2KsHLHvOQAlRDkyYStHwSwWgzq3uiM6AUGGbbceFEI6SoR3dYhTwVpqRjGCA0Rg/FBt1K7wIsPcLWr8cXo3zQ@uXE/IQ4M2FFzEOVC4CNcuAvw/4VcCvA/wQxGzg5SQ3oMrBO9H@yzoJ6k5wUDVt2R1BwgU97ARYpyB5mJycKvSygkH5yrmJ3cafsArZnKXboPGcVMjmrNzGCzxH0Q34m0lzjF@d6LKlgDjljYoRTnoWcfU@fPoc8xjcAY70BT9GfGtZJUMzioCG4GqnHnysCGSJrWfwRc72UQsa3NJKRMt6o4w2z0pDYFogh@KL1lSJodg2p3jsRTFy1Dbg8GXmawWStaGCsC1yPZCvh9BFPWTKfTjsZLPfHUF1VCU7xoI5IuESbDw0V5UmnNiB0S10B2F7ijHasmhkhQ/FQejIKj1/Ujqam0UEBgqEaYehb@SIIZ2gMBqZm17uQAzRZRBMoMkYSxAdVU4mcEEjuwi7YVMc@8kccbUbMhljCbWE3bCXIPAVa@wbIOq6Z/KaRXziEP@JQXziD//f7CF4ag@fuMN/bo4rQPCvzRHLsJd2k0zcJaGRHxk9EO2jPefXPBQLP6zZL//bQzLx0Mf@hjP@LFyfDHoTBJy@aHAY104mDnJ/kLZ4NdpuNcHHF/VrIYoavhfq60FLyWTDWURZDdT3pKmPSdOq7Cd9Zw7074s0j2bs@54RyeiTrV30skuG3EyDBEOM5vZMzvW3KM2@MfZVgSRNoxnX97C6oVaKC98imtmKT7QhshH6q1VomHBU2KTC5hUuleJUy2Ek0drm4FV6OpQsXt36HFtKmTRrapf6ppgMl4N917QyqeO/ymbHaA6M3OLkVZ@HvsXJroqYWnSaEOc4jaJadMZTVdKsfdbvd41M4j9ibfPQ@N2Wka9N@2xjT/r6pjtnWaZqzHQN@@6rIl3ZPrNEWYPwHdIlZrI76sWE6f8JYdBmk@bDY67jk6mSQ3w@qUC9xu6Jq3z2nbC9BP@UuwN733WiU7aUff/yAw)

### "Fifth" program: A=20, B=360

I noticed that @thedefault.'s answer, while having an impressively low A, had a very high B. I looked to see what I could do to remedy that. My first step was to invert the sense of the first half of the lookup table, so that `not` could be calculated directly rather than by adding `9` and taking the sign. The next step was to swap the two halves of the table, so that `and` only took two operations, and the decimal output function could also be simplified. However this meant that `or` was too inefficient, particularly when used to add modulo 7, so I rewrote that to reduce the inefficiency. This is the generator program that I ended up with:

```python
import functools
print("""
T = {
 "00": "1", "01":"2", "02":"3", "03":"4", "04":"5", "05":"6", "06":"7", "07":"8", "08":"9", "09":"0"
,
 "10": "1", "11":"0", "12":"0", "13":"0", "14":"0", "15":"0", "16":"0", "17":"0", "18":"0", "19":"0"
}
""".strip())

varn = 0
def getvar():
    global varn
    ret = 'v' + str(varn)
    varn += 1
    return ret
def enot(bi):
    ni = getvar()
    print('%s = T["1"+%s]' % (ni, bi))
    return ni
def enand(b1, b2): #result may be greater than 1, use enot(eand()) to avoid this
    ni = getvar()
    print('%s = T[%s+%s]' % (ni, b1, b2))
    return ni
def eand(b1, b2):
    return enot(enand(b1, b2))
def eor(b1, b2):
    return enot(eand(enot(b1), enot(b2)))
def eeqt(vi):
    #return array of 10 bits for all 10 possible values of vi.
    res = []
    vi2 = getvar()
    for i in range(10):
        ni = getvar()
        print('%s = T["1"+%s]' % (ni, vi if i == 0 else vi2))
        print('%s = T["0"+%s]' % (vi2, vi if i == 0 else vi2))
        res.append(ni)
    #e.g. res[0] = !(x == 0)
    return res[:1] + res[:0:-1]
def edmon(m1, m2):
    #decode m2 using eeqt. create 2 more variables for november and december
    #m1 is already boolean
    m2p = eeqt(m2)
    v11 = eand(m2p[1], m1)
    m2p[1] = eand(m2p[1], enot(m1))
    v12 = eand(m2p[2], m1)
    m2p[2] = eand(m2p[2], enot(m1))
    return m2p[1:] + m2p[:1] + [v11, v12]
def elmon(dmon):
    #given output of edmon, find first day modulo 7.
    #table = [4, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0, 2]
    d0 = enot(eand(eand(enot(dmon[1]), enot(dmon[2])), enot(dmon[10])))
    d1 = dmon[5]
    d2 = eor(dmon[8], dmon[11])
    d3 = eor(dmon[3], dmon[6])
    d4 = eor(dmon[0], dmon[9])
    d5 = dmon[4]
    d6 = dmon[7]
    return [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6]
def eadd7(v1, v2):
    vals = [['"1"'] for _ in range(7)]
    for a in range(7):
        for b in range(7):
            if v2[b] != '"0"':
                vals[(a+b)%7].append(enand(v1[a], v2[b]))
    return [enot(functools.reduce(eand, a)) for a in vals]
def emod7(d2):
    et = eeqt(d2)
    et[0] = eor(et[0], et[7])
    et[1] = eor(et[1], et[8])
    et[2] = eor(et[2], et[9])
    return et[:7]
def e3mod7(d1):
    et = eeqt(d1) # can't optimize because entries are obtained like 0, 9, 8, ... and 1 must be reached
    #d1 < 4. multiply by 3
    #0*3 = 0, 1*3 = 3, 2*3 = 6, 3*3 = 2
    return [et[0], '"0"', et[3], et[1], '"0"', '"0"', et[2]]
def eout(m7):
    val = '"1"'
    ni = getvar()
    for x in m7:
        print('%s = T[%s+%s]' % (ni, x, val))
        val = ni
    return ni
def solve(m1, m2, d1, d2):
    mmod7 = elmon(edmon(m1, m2))
    dmod7 = eadd7(emod7(d2), e3mod7(d1))
    res = eadd7(mmod7, dmod7)
    res = res[1:] + res[:1]
    return eout(res[::-1])

print('output =', solve('m1', 'm2', 'd1', 'd2'))
```

Comment: I think overlapping one entry between the two tables to reduce A by 1 is possible.

Comment: @user202729 Ah yes, I see what you mean now, thanks.

Comment: You managed to get B=360 for the optimal A solution... // Perhaps I'll write something to combine tables automatically to reduce A for the other solutions, because if there's one overlapping output entry in two separate tables then it's always possible to combine them.

Comment: @user202729 ...because in the worst case you can define `m` to be `00000000000`, while `b` is replaced by a suffix of `00000000006`, with appropriate transformations for my other tables?

Comment: @user202729 Although I see I can overlap `x00` with `o`, saving two entries.

Comment: @user202729 And `a00` overlaps `h`, for another two saved!

Comment: Yes, so the A-score of the 2nd/3rd/4th program can be reduced by 3. (although it's obvious that it's possible, there's a program to actually generate these programs in the chat room)

Comment: @user202729 Four, actually: I've just overlapped `haCDE` as `00CDE` with `oxXYZ` as `ZYX01` to reduce the A-score by two, and then the other tables can be overlapped for another two.

Answer (score 2):

## Score: 26310277, A=20, B=2618, combined score 332345

The `A` is fairly likely to be optimal. (of course, the `B` is terrible)

```python
T = {
 "00": "0", "01":"1", "02":"1", "03":"1", "04":"1", "05":"1", "06":"1", "07":"1", "08":"1", "09":"1",
 "10": "1", "11":"2", "12":"3", "13":"4", "14":"5", "15":"6", "16":"7", "17":"8", "18":"9", "19":"0"
}
v1 = T["0"+m2]
v0 = T["1"+m2]
v2 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v3 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v4 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v5 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v6 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v7 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v8 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v9 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v10 = T["0"+v0]
v0 = T["1"+v0]
v11 = T["1"+m1]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v11 = T["1"+v11]
v12 = T["0"+v11]
v13 = T[v10+v12]
v13 = T["0"+v13]
v14 = T[v10+m1]
v14 = T["0"+v14]
v15 = T["1"+m1]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v15 = T["1"+v15]
v16 = T["0"+v15]
v17 = T[v9+v16]
v17 = T["0"+v17]
v18 = T[v9+m1]
v18 = T["0"+v18]
v19 = T[v18+v8]
v20 = T["1"+v19]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["1"+v20]
v20 = T["0"+v20]
v21 = T["1"+v20]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v21 = T["1"+v21]
v22 = T["0"+v21]
v23 = T[v22+v13]
v24 = T["1"+v23]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["1"+v24]
v24 = T["0"+v24]
v25 = T["1"+v24]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v25 = T["1"+v25]
v26 = T["0"+v25]
v27 = T[v2+v17]
v28 = T["1"+v27]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["1"+v28]
v28 = T["0"+v28]
v29 = T["1"+v28]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v29 = T["1"+v29]
v30 = T["0"+v29]
v31 = T[v7+v4]
v32 = T["1"+v31]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["1"+v32]
v32 = T["0"+v32]
v33 = T["1"+v32]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v33 = T["1"+v33]
v34 = T["0"+v33]
v35 = T[v14+v1]
v36 = T["1"+v35]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["1"+v36]
v36 = T["0"+v36]
v37 = T["1"+v36]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v37 = T["1"+v37]
v38 = T["0"+v37]
v40 = T["0"+d2]
v39 = T["1"+d2]
v41 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v42 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v43 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v44 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v45 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v46 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v47 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v48 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v49 = T["0"+v39]
v39 = T["1"+v39]
v50 = T["1"+v40]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v50 = T["1"+v50]
v51 = T["0"+v50]
v52 = T["1"+v49]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v52 = T["1"+v52]
v53 = T["0"+v52]
v54 = T["1"+v48]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v54 = T["1"+v54]
v55 = T["0"+v54]
v56 = T["1"+v47]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v56 = T["1"+v56]
v57 = T["0"+v56]
v58 = T["1"+v46]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v58 = T["1"+v58]
v59 = T["0"+v58]
v60 = T["1"+v45]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v60 = T["1"+v60]
v61 = T["0"+v60]
v62 = T["1"+v44]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v62 = T["1"+v62]
v63 = T["0"+v62]
v64 = T["1"+v43]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v64 = T["1"+v64]
v65 = T["0"+v64]
v66 = T["1"+v42]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v66 = T["1"+v66]
v67 = T["0"+v66]
v68 = T["1"+v41]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v68 = T["1"+v68]
v69 = T["0"+v68]
v70 = T[v51+v65]
v70 = T["0"+v70]
v71 = T[v53+v67]
v71 = T["0"+v71]
v72 = T[v55+v69]
v72 = T["0"+v72]
v74 = T["0"+d1]
v73 = T["1"+d1]
v75 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v76 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v77 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v78 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v79 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v80 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v81 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v82 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v83 = T["0"+v73]
v73 = T["1"+v73]
v84 = T["1"+v74]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v84 = T["1"+v84]
v85 = T["0"+v84]
v86 = T["1"+v81]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v86 = T["1"+v86]
v87 = T["0"+v86]
v88 = T["1"+v83]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v88 = T["1"+v88]
v89 = T["0"+v88]
v90 = T["1"+v82]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v90 = T["1"+v90]
v91 = T["0"+v90]
v92 = T[v70+v85]
v93 = T["1"+v92]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["1"+v93]
v93 = T["0"+v93]
v94 = T["1"+v93]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v94 = T["1"+v94]
v95 = T["0"+v94]
v96 = T[v70+"0"]
v97 = T["1"+v96]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["1"+v97]
v97 = T["0"+v97]
v98 = T["1"+v97]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v98 = T["1"+v98]
v99 = T["0"+v98]
v100 = T[v70+v87]
v101 = T["1"+v100]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["1"+v101]
v101 = T["0"+v101]
v102 = T["1"+v101]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v102 = T["1"+v102]
v103 = T["0"+v102]
v104 = T[v70+v89]
v105 = T["1"+v104]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["1"+v105]
v105 = T["0"+v105]
v106 = T["1"+v105]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v106 = T["1"+v106]
v107 = T["0"+v106]
v108 = T[v70+"0"]
v109 = T["1"+v108]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["1"+v109]
v109 = T["0"+v109]
v110 = T["1"+v109]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v110 = T["1"+v110]
v111 = T["0"+v110]
v112 = T[v70+"0"]
v113 = T["1"+v112]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["1"+v113]
v113 = T["0"+v113]
v114 = T["1"+v113]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v114 = T["1"+v114]
v115 = T["0"+v114]
v116 = T[v70+v91]
v117 = T["1"+v116]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["1"+v117]
v117 = T["0"+v117]
v118 = T["1"+v117]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v118 = T["1"+v118]
v119 = T["0"+v118]
v120 = T[v71+v85]
v121 = T["1"+v120]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["1"+v121]
v121 = T["0"+v121]
v122 = T["1"+v121]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v122 = T["1"+v122]
v123 = T["0"+v122]
v124 = T[v71+"0"]
v125 = T["1"+v124]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["1"+v125]
v125 = T["0"+v125]
v126 = T["1"+v125]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v126 = T["1"+v126]
v127 = T["0"+v126]
v128 = T[v71+v87]
v129 = T["1"+v128]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["1"+v129]
v129 = T["0"+v129]
v130 = T["1"+v129]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v130 = T["1"+v130]
v131 = T["0"+v130]
v132 = T[v71+v89]
v133 = T["1"+v132]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["1"+v133]
v133 = T["0"+v133]
v134 = T["1"+v133]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v134 = T["1"+v134]
v135 = T["0"+v134]
v136 = T[v71+"0"]
v137 = T["1"+v136]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["1"+v137]
v137 = T["0"+v137]
v138 = T["1"+v137]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v138 = T["1"+v138]
v139 = T["0"+v138]
v140 = T[v71+"0"]
v141 = T["1"+v140]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["1"+v141]
v141 = T["0"+v141]
v142 = T["1"+v141]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v142 = T["1"+v142]
v143 = T["0"+v142]
v144 = T[v71+v91]
v145 = T["1"+v144]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["1"+v145]
v145 = T["0"+v145]
v146 = T["1"+v145]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v146 = T["1"+v146]
v147 = T["0"+v146]
v148 = T[v72+v85]
v149 = T["1"+v148]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["1"+v149]
v149 = T["0"+v149]
v150 = T["1"+v149]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v150 = T["1"+v150]
v151 = T["0"+v150]
v152 = T[v72+"0"]
v153 = T["1"+v152]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["1"+v153]
v153 = T["0"+v153]
v154 = T["1"+v153]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v154 = T["1"+v154]
v155 = T["0"+v154]
v156 = T[v72+v87]
v157 = T["1"+v156]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["1"+v157]
v157 = T["0"+v157]
v158 = T["1"+v157]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v158 = T["1"+v158]
v159 = T["0"+v158]
v160 = T[v72+v89]
v161 = T["1"+v160]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["1"+v161]
v161 = T["0"+v161]
v162 = T["1"+v161]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v162 = T["1"+v162]
v163 = T["0"+v162]
v164 = T[v72+"0"]
v165 = T["1"+v164]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["1"+v165]
v165 = T["0"+v165]
v166 = T["1"+v165]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v166 = T["1"+v166]
v167 = T["0"+v166]
v168 = T[v72+"0"]
v169 = T["1"+v168]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["1"+v169]
v169 = T["0"+v169]
v170 = T["1"+v169]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v170 = T["1"+v170]
v171 = T["0"+v170]
v172 = T[v72+v91]
v173 = T["1"+v172]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["1"+v173]
v173 = T["0"+v173]
v174 = T["1"+v173]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v174 = T["1"+v174]
v175 = T["0"+v174]
v176 = T[v57+v85]
v177 = T["1"+v176]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["1"+v177]
v177 = T["0"+v177]
v178 = T["1"+v177]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v178 = T["1"+v178]
v179 = T["0"+v178]
v180 = T[v57+"0"]
v181 = T["1"+v180]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["1"+v181]
v181 = T["0"+v181]
v182 = T["1"+v181]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v182 = T["1"+v182]
v183 = T["0"+v182]
v184 = T[v57+v87]
v185 = T["1"+v184]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["1"+v185]
v185 = T["0"+v185]
v186 = T["1"+v185]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v186 = T["1"+v186]
v187 = T["0"+v186]
v188 = T[v57+v89]
v189 = T["1"+v188]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["1"+v189]
v189 = T["0"+v189]
v190 = T["1"+v189]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v190 = T["1"+v190]
v191 = T["0"+v190]
v192 = T[v57+"0"]
v193 = T["1"+v192]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["1"+v193]
v193 = T["0"+v193]
v194 = T["1"+v193]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v194 = T["1"+v194]
v195 = T["0"+v194]
v196 = T[v57+"0"]
v197 = T["1"+v196]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["1"+v197]
v197 = T["0"+v197]
v198 = T["1"+v197]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v198 = T["1"+v198]
v199 = T["0"+v198]
v200 = T[v57+v91]
v201 = T["1"+v200]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["1"+v201]
v201 = T["0"+v201]
v202 = T["1"+v201]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v202 = T["1"+v202]
v203 = T["0"+v202]
v204 = T[v59+v85]
v205 = T["1"+v204]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["1"+v205]
v205 = T["0"+v205]
v206 = T["1"+v205]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v206 = T["1"+v206]
v207 = T["0"+v206]
v208 = T[v59+"0"]
v209 = T["1"+v208]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["1"+v209]
v209 = T["0"+v209]
v210 = T["1"+v209]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v210 = T["1"+v210]
v211 = T["0"+v210]
v212 = T[v59+v87]
v213 = T["1"+v212]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["1"+v213]
v213 = T["0"+v213]
v214 = T["1"+v213]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v214 = T["1"+v214]
v215 = T["0"+v214]
v216 = T[v59+v89]
v217 = T["1"+v216]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["1"+v217]
v217 = T["0"+v217]
v218 = T["1"+v217]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v218 = T["1"+v218]
v219 = T["0"+v218]
v220 = T[v59+"0"]
v221 = T["1"+v220]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["1"+v221]
v221 = T["0"+v221]
v222 = T["1"+v221]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v222 = T["1"+v222]
v223 = T["0"+v222]
v224 = T[v59+"0"]
v225 = T["1"+v224]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["1"+v225]
v225 = T["0"+v225]
v226 = T["1"+v225]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v226 = T["1"+v226]
v227 = T["0"+v226]
v228 = T[v59+v91]
v229 = T["1"+v228]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["1"+v229]
v229 = T["0"+v229]
v230 = T["1"+v229]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v230 = T["1"+v230]
v231 = T["0"+v230]
v232 = T[v61+v85]
v233 = T["1"+v232]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["1"+v233]
v233 = T["0"+v233]
v234 = T["1"+v233]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v234 = T["1"+v234]
v235 = T["0"+v234]
v236 = T[v61+"0"]
v237 = T["1"+v236]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["1"+v237]
v237 = T["0"+v237]
v238 = T["1"+v237]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v238 = T["1"+v238]
v239 = T["0"+v238]
v240 = T[v61+v87]
v241 = T["1"+v240]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["1"+v241]
v241 = T["0"+v241]
v242 = T["1"+v241]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v242 = T["1"+v242]
v243 = T["0"+v242]
v244 = T[v61+v89]
v245 = T["1"+v244]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["1"+v245]
v245 = T["0"+v245]
v246 = T["1"+v245]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v246 = T["1"+v246]
v247 = T["0"+v246]
v248 = T[v61+"0"]
v249 = T["1"+v248]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["1"+v249]
v249 = T["0"+v249]
v250 = T["1"+v249]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v250 = T["1"+v250]
v251 = T["0"+v250]
v252 = T[v61+"0"]
v253 = T["1"+v252]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["1"+v253]
v253 = T["0"+v253]
v254 = T["1"+v253]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v254 = T["1"+v254]
v255 = T["0"+v254]
v256 = T[v61+v91]
v257 = T["1"+v256]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["1"+v257]
v257 = T["0"+v257]
v258 = T["1"+v257]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v258 = T["1"+v258]
v259 = T["0"+v258]
v260 = T[v63+v85]
v261 = T["1"+v260]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["1"+v261]
v261 = T["0"+v261]
v262 = T["1"+v261]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v262 = T["1"+v262]
v263 = T["0"+v262]
v264 = T[v63+"0"]
v265 = T["1"+v264]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["1"+v265]
v265 = T["0"+v265]
v266 = T["1"+v265]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v266 = T["1"+v266]
v267 = T["0"+v266]
v268 = T[v63+v87]
v269 = T["1"+v268]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["1"+v269]
v269 = T["0"+v269]
v270 = T["1"+v269]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v270 = T["1"+v270]
v271 = T["0"+v270]
v272 = T[v63+v89]
v273 = T["1"+v272]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["1"+v273]
v273 = T["0"+v273]
v274 = T["1"+v273]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v274 = T["1"+v274]
v275 = T["0"+v274]
v276 = T[v63+"0"]
v277 = T["1"+v276]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["1"+v277]
v277 = T["0"+v277]
v278 = T["1"+v277]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v278 = T["1"+v278]
v279 = T["0"+v278]
v280 = T[v63+"0"]
v281 = T["1"+v280]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["1"+v281]
v281 = T["0"+v281]
v282 = T["1"+v281]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v282 = T["1"+v282]
v283 = T["0"+v282]
v284 = T[v63+v91]
v285 = T["1"+v284]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["1"+v285]
v285 = T["0"+v285]
v286 = T["1"+v285]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v286 = T["1"+v286]
v287 = T["0"+v286]
v288 = T[v95+v147]
v288 = T["0"+v288]
v289 = T[v288+v171]
v289 = T["0"+v289]
v290 = T[v289+v195]
v290 = T["0"+v290]
v291 = T[v290+v219]
v291 = T["0"+v291]
v292 = T[v291+v243]
v292 = T["0"+v292]
v293 = T[v292+v267]
v293 = T["0"+v293]
v294 = T[v99+v123]
v294 = T["0"+v294]
v295 = T[v294+v175]
v295 = T["0"+v295]
v296 = T[v295+v199]
v296 = T["0"+v296]
v297 = T[v296+v223]
v297 = T["0"+v297]
v298 = T[v297+v247]
v298 = T["0"+v298]
v299 = T[v298+v271]
v299 = T["0"+v299]
v300 = T[v103+v127]
v300 = T["0"+v300]
v301 = T[v300+v151]
v301 = T["0"+v301]
v302 = T[v301+v203]
v302 = T["0"+v302]
v303 = T[v302+v227]
v303 = T["0"+v303]
v304 = T[v303+v251]
v304 = T["0"+v304]
v305 = T[v304+v275]
v305 = T["0"+v305]
v306 = T[v107+v131]
v306 = T["0"+v306]
v307 = T[v306+v155]
v307 = T["0"+v307]
v308 = T[v307+v179]
v308 = T["0"+v308]
v309 = T[v308+v231]
v309 = T["0"+v309]
v310 = T[v309+v255]
v310 = T["0"+v310]
v311 = T[v310+v279]
v311 = T["0"+v311]
v312 = T[v111+v135]
v312 = T["0"+v312]
v313 = T[v312+v159]
v313 = T["0"+v313]
v314 = T[v313+v183]
v314 = T["0"+v314]
v315 = T[v314+v207]
v315 = T["0"+v315]
v316 = T[v315+v259]
v316 = T["0"+v316]
v317 = T[v316+v283]
v317 = T["0"+v317]
v318 = T[v115+v139]
v318 = T["0"+v318]
v319 = T[v318+v163]
v319 = T["0"+v319]
v320 = T[v319+v187]
v320 = T["0"+v320]
v321 = T[v320+v211]
v321 = T["0"+v321]
v322 = T[v321+v235]
v322 = T["0"+v322]
v323 = T[v322+v287]
v323 = T["0"+v323]
v324 = T[v119+v143]
v324 = T["0"+v324]
v325 = T[v324+v167]
v325 = T["0"+v325]
v326 = T[v325+v191]
v326 = T["0"+v326]
v327 = T[v326+v215]
v327 = T["0"+v327]
v328 = T[v327+v239]
v328 = T["0"+v328]
v329 = T[v328+v263]
v329 = T["0"+v329]
v330 = T["1"+v26]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v330 = T["1"+v330]
v331 = T["0"+v330]
v332 = T["1"+v5]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v332 = T["1"+v332]
v333 = T["0"+v332]
v334 = T["1"+v30]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v334 = T["1"+v334]
v335 = T["0"+v334]
v336 = T["1"+v34]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v336 = T["1"+v336]
v337 = T["0"+v336]
v338 = T["1"+v38]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v338 = T["1"+v338]
v339 = T["0"+v338]
v340 = T["1"+v6]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v340 = T["1"+v340]
v341 = T["0"+v340]
v342 = T["1"+v3]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v342 = T["1"+v342]
v343 = T["0"+v342]
v344 = T[v331+v293]
v345 = T["1"+v344]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["1"+v345]
v345 = T["0"+v345]
v346 = T["1"+v345]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v346 = T["1"+v346]
v347 = T["0"+v346]
v348 = T[v331+v299]
v349 = T["1"+v348]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["1"+v349]
v349 = T["0"+v349]
v350 = T["1"+v349]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v350 = T["1"+v350]
v351 = T["0"+v350]
v352 = T[v331+v305]
v353 = T["1"+v352]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["1"+v353]
v353 = T["0"+v353]
v354 = T["1"+v353]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v354 = T["1"+v354]
v355 = T["0"+v354]
v356 = T[v331+v311]
v357 = T["1"+v356]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["1"+v357]
v357 = T["0"+v357]
v358 = T["1"+v357]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v358 = T["1"+v358]
v359 = T["0"+v358]
v360 = T[v331+v317]
v361 = T["1"+v360]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["1"+v361]
v361 = T["0"+v361]
v362 = T["1"+v361]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v362 = T["1"+v362]
v363 = T["0"+v362]
v364 = T[v331+v323]
v365 = T["1"+v364]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["1"+v365]
v365 = T["0"+v365]
v366 = T["1"+v365]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v366 = T["1"+v366]
v367 = T["0"+v366]
v368 = T[v331+v329]
v369 = T["1"+v368]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["1"+v369]
v369 = T["0"+v369]
v370 = T["1"+v369]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v370 = T["1"+v370]
v371 = T["0"+v370]
v372 = T[v333+v293]
v373 = T["1"+v372]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["1"+v373]
v373 = T["0"+v373]
v374 = T["1"+v373]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v374 = T["1"+v374]
v375 = T["0"+v374]
v376 = T[v333+v299]
v377 = T["1"+v376]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["1"+v377]
v377 = T["0"+v377]
v378 = T["1"+v377]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v378 = T["1"+v378]
v379 = T["0"+v378]
v380 = T[v333+v305]
v381 = T["1"+v380]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["1"+v381]
v381 = T["0"+v381]
v382 = T["1"+v381]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v382 = T["1"+v382]
v383 = T["0"+v382]
v384 = T[v333+v311]
v385 = T["1"+v384]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["1"+v385]
v385 = T["0"+v385]
v386 = T["1"+v385]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v386 = T["1"+v386]
v387 = T["0"+v386]
v388 = T[v333+v317]
v389 = T["1"+v388]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["1"+v389]
v389 = T["0"+v389]
v390 = T["1"+v389]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v390 = T["1"+v390]
v391 = T["0"+v390]
v392 = T[v333+v323]
v393 = T["1"+v392]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["1"+v393]
v393 = T["0"+v393]
v394 = T["1"+v393]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v394 = T["1"+v394]
v395 = T["0"+v394]
v396 = T[v333+v329]
v397 = T["1"+v396]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["1"+v397]
v397 = T["0"+v397]
v398 = T["1"+v397]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v398 = T["1"+v398]
v399 = T["0"+v398]
v400 = T[v335+v293]
v401 = T["1"+v400]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["1"+v401]
v401 = T["0"+v401]
v402 = T["1"+v401]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v402 = T["1"+v402]
v403 = T["0"+v402]
v404 = T[v335+v299]
v405 = T["1"+v404]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["1"+v405]
v405 = T["0"+v405]
v406 = T["1"+v405]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v406 = T["1"+v406]
v407 = T["0"+v406]
v408 = T[v335+v305]
v409 = T["1"+v408]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["1"+v409]
v409 = T["0"+v409]
v410 = T["1"+v409]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v410 = T["1"+v410]
v411 = T["0"+v410]
v412 = T[v335+v311]
v413 = T["1"+v412]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["1"+v413]
v413 = T["0"+v413]
v414 = T["1"+v413]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v414 = T["1"+v414]
v415 = T["0"+v414]
v416 = T[v335+v317]
v417 = T["1"+v416]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["1"+v417]
v417 = T["0"+v417]
v418 = T["1"+v417]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v418 = T["1"+v418]
v419 = T["0"+v418]
v420 = T[v335+v323]
v421 = T["1"+v420]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["1"+v421]
v421 = T["0"+v421]
v422 = T["1"+v421]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v422 = T["1"+v422]
v423 = T["0"+v422]
v424 = T[v335+v329]
v425 = T["1"+v424]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["1"+v425]
v425 = T["0"+v425]
v426 = T["1"+v425]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v426 = T["1"+v426]
v427 = T["0"+v426]
v428 = T[v337+v293]
v429 = T["1"+v428]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["1"+v429]
v429 = T["0"+v429]
v430 = T["1"+v429]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v430 = T["1"+v430]
v431 = T["0"+v430]
v432 = T[v337+v299]
v433 = T["1"+v432]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["1"+v433]
v433 = T["0"+v433]
v434 = T["1"+v433]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v434 = T["1"+v434]
v435 = T["0"+v434]
v436 = T[v337+v305]
v437 = T["1"+v436]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["1"+v437]
v437 = T["0"+v437]
v438 = T["1"+v437]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v438 = T["1"+v438]
v439 = T["0"+v438]
v440 = T[v337+v311]
v441 = T["1"+v440]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["1"+v441]
v441 = T["0"+v441]
v442 = T["1"+v441]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v442 = T["1"+v442]
v443 = T["0"+v442]
v444 = T[v337+v317]
v445 = T["1"+v444]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["1"+v445]
v445 = T["0"+v445]
v446 = T["1"+v445]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v446 = T["1"+v446]
v447 = T["0"+v446]
v448 = T[v337+v323]
v449 = T["1"+v448]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["1"+v449]
v449 = T["0"+v449]
v450 = T["1"+v449]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v450 = T["1"+v450]
v451 = T["0"+v450]
v452 = T[v337+v329]
v453 = T["1"+v452]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["1"+v453]
v453 = T["0"+v453]
v454 = T["1"+v453]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v454 = T["1"+v454]
v455 = T["0"+v454]
v456 = T[v339+v293]
v457 = T["1"+v456]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["1"+v457]
v457 = T["0"+v457]
v458 = T["1"+v457]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v458 = T["1"+v458]
v459 = T["0"+v458]
v460 = T[v339+v299]
v461 = T["1"+v460]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["1"+v461]
v461 = T["0"+v461]
v462 = T["1"+v461]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v462 = T["1"+v462]
v463 = T["0"+v462]
v464 = T[v339+v305]
v465 = T["1"+v464]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["1"+v465]
v465 = T["0"+v465]
v466 = T["1"+v465]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v466 = T["1"+v466]
v467 = T["0"+v466]
v468 = T[v339+v311]
v469 = T["1"+v468]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["1"+v469]
v469 = T["0"+v469]
v470 = T["1"+v469]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v470 = T["1"+v470]
v471 = T["0"+v470]
v472 = T[v339+v317]
v473 = T["1"+v472]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["1"+v473]
v473 = T["0"+v473]
v474 = T["1"+v473]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v474 = T["1"+v474]
v475 = T["0"+v474]
v476 = T[v339+v323]
v477 = T["1"+v476]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["1"+v477]
v477 = T["0"+v477]
v478 = T["1"+v477]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v478 = T["1"+v478]
v479 = T["0"+v478]
v480 = T[v339+v329]
v481 = T["1"+v480]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["1"+v481]
v481 = T["0"+v481]
v482 = T["1"+v481]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v482 = T["1"+v482]
v483 = T["0"+v482]
v484 = T[v341+v293]
v485 = T["1"+v484]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["1"+v485]
v485 = T["0"+v485]
v486 = T["1"+v485]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v486 = T["1"+v486]
v487 = T["0"+v486]
v488 = T[v341+v299]
v489 = T["1"+v488]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["1"+v489]
v489 = T["0"+v489]
v490 = T["1"+v489]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v490 = T["1"+v490]
v491 = T["0"+v490]
v492 = T[v341+v305]
v493 = T["1"+v492]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["1"+v493]
v493 = T["0"+v493]
v494 = T["1"+v493]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v494 = T["1"+v494]
v495 = T["0"+v494]
v496 = T[v341+v311]
v497 = T["1"+v496]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["1"+v497]
v497 = T["0"+v497]
v498 = T["1"+v497]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v498 = T["1"+v498]
v499 = T["0"+v498]
v500 = T[v341+v317]
v501 = T["1"+v500]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["1"+v501]
v501 = T["0"+v501]
v502 = T["1"+v501]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v502 = T["1"+v502]
v503 = T["0"+v502]
v504 = T[v341+v323]
v505 = T["1"+v504]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["1"+v505]
v505 = T["0"+v505]
v506 = T["1"+v505]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v506 = T["1"+v506]
v507 = T["0"+v506]
v508 = T[v341+v329]
v509 = T["1"+v508]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["1"+v509]
v509 = T["0"+v509]
v510 = T["1"+v509]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v510 = T["1"+v510]
v511 = T["0"+v510]
v512 = T[v343+v293]
v513 = T["1"+v512]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["1"+v513]
v513 = T["0"+v513]
v514 = T["1"+v513]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v514 = T["1"+v514]
v515 = T["0"+v514]
v516 = T[v343+v299]
v517 = T["1"+v516]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["1"+v517]
v517 = T["0"+v517]
v518 = T["1"+v517]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v518 = T["1"+v518]
v519 = T["0"+v518]
v520 = T[v343+v305]
v521 = T["1"+v520]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["1"+v521]
v521 = T["0"+v521]
v522 = T["1"+v521]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v522 = T["1"+v522]
v523 = T["0"+v522]
v524 = T[v343+v311]
v525 = T["1"+v524]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["1"+v525]
v525 = T["0"+v525]
v526 = T["1"+v525]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v526 = T["1"+v526]
v527 = T["0"+v526]
v528 = T[v343+v317]
v529 = T["1"+v528]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["1"+v529]
v529 = T["0"+v529]
v530 = T["1"+v529]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v530 = T["1"+v530]
v531 = T["0"+v530]
v532 = T[v343+v323]
v533 = T["1"+v532]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["1"+v533]
v533 = T["0"+v533]
v534 = T["1"+v533]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v534 = T["1"+v534]
v535 = T["0"+v534]
v536 = T[v343+v329]
v537 = T["1"+v536]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["1"+v537]
v537 = T["0"+v537]
v538 = T["1"+v537]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v538 = T["1"+v538]
v539 = T["0"+v538]
v540 = T[v347+v399]
v540 = T["0"+v540]
v541 = T[v540+v423]
v541 = T["0"+v541]
v542 = T[v541+v447]
v542 = T["0"+v542]
v543 = T[v542+v471]
v543 = T["0"+v543]
v544 = T[v543+v495]
v544 = T["0"+v544]
v545 = T[v544+v519]
v545 = T["0"+v545]
v546 = T[v351+v375]
v546 = T["0"+v546]
v547 = T[v546+v427]
v547 = T["0"+v547]
v548 = T[v547+v451]
v548 = T["0"+v548]
v549 = T[v548+v475]
v549 = T["0"+v549]
v550 = T[v549+v499]
v550 = T["0"+v550]
v551 = T[v550+v523]
v551 = T["0"+v551]
v552 = T[v355+v379]
v552 = T["0"+v552]
v553 = T[v552+v403]
v553 = T["0"+v553]
v554 = T[v553+v455]
v554 = T["0"+v554]
v555 = T[v554+v479]
v555 = T["0"+v555]
v556 = T[v555+v503]
v556 = T["0"+v556]
v557 = T[v556+v527]
v557 = T["0"+v557]
v558 = T[v359+v383]
v558 = T["0"+v558]
v559 = T[v558+v407]
v559 = T["0"+v559]
v560 = T[v559+v431]
v560 = T["0"+v560]
v561 = T[v560+v483]
v561 = T["0"+v561]
v562 = T[v561+v507]
v562 = T["0"+v562]
v563 = T[v562+v531]
v563 = T["0"+v563]
v564 = T[v363+v387]
v564 = T["0"+v564]
v565 = T[v564+v411]
v565 = T["0"+v565]
v566 = T[v565+v435]
v566 = T["0"+v566]
v567 = T[v566+v459]
v567 = T["0"+v567]
v568 = T[v567+v511]
v568 = T["0"+v568]
v569 = T[v568+v535]
v569 = T["0"+v569]
v570 = T[v367+v391]
v570 = T["0"+v570]
v571 = T[v570+v415]
v571 = T["0"+v571]
v572 = T[v571+v439]
v572 = T["0"+v572]
v573 = T[v572+v463]
v573 = T["0"+v573]
v574 = T[v573+v487]
v574 = T["0"+v574]
v575 = T[v574+v539]
v575 = T["0"+v575]
v576 = T[v371+v395]
v576 = T["0"+v576]
v577 = T[v576+v419]
v577 = T["0"+v577]
v578 = T[v577+v443]
v578 = T["0"+v578]
v579 = T[v578+v467]
v579 = T["0"+v579]
v580 = T[v579+v491]
v580 = T["0"+v580]
v581 = T[v580+v515]
v581 = T["0"+v581]
v582 = T["1"+v545]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v582 = T["1"+v582]
v583 = T["0"+v582]
v584 = T["1"+v581]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v584 = T["1"+v584]
v585 = T["0"+v584]
v586 = T["1"+v575]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v586 = T["1"+v586]
v587 = T["0"+v586]
v588 = T["1"+v569]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v588 = T["1"+v588]
v589 = T["0"+v588]
v590 = T["1"+v563]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v590 = T["1"+v590]
v591 = T["0"+v590]
v592 = T["1"+v557]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v592 = T["1"+v592]
v593 = T["0"+v592]
v594 = T["1"+v551]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v594 = T["1"+v594]
v595 = T["0"+v594]
v596 = T[v583+"1"]
v596 = T[v585+v596]
v596 = T[v587+v596]
v596 = T[v589+v596]
v596 = T[v591+v596]
v596 = T[v593+v596]
v596 = T[v595+v596]
v597 = T["1"+v596]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
v597 = T["1"+v597]
output = v597
```

Generator code:

```python
import functools
print("""
T = {
 "00": "0", "01":"1", "02":"1", "03":"1", "04":"1", "05":"1", "06":"1", "07":"1", "08":"1", "09":"1",
 "10": "1", "11":"2", "12":"3", "13":"4", "14":"5", "15":"6", "16":"7", "17":"8", "18":"9", "19":"0"
}
""".strip())

varn = 0
def getvar():
    global varn
    ret = 'v' + str(varn)
    varn += 1
    return ret
def eaddi(vi, imm):
    if imm == 0: return vi
    ni = getvar()
    for i in range(imm):
        print('%s = T["1"+%s]' % (ni, vi if i == 0 else ni))
    return ni
def enot(bi):
    bi2 = eaddi(bi, 9)
    ni = getvar()
    print('%s = T["0"+%s]' % (ni, bi2))
    return ni
def eor(b1, b2):
    ni = getvar()
    print('%s = T[%s+%s]' % (ni, b1, b2))
    print('%s = T["0"+%s]' % (ni, ni))
    return ni
def enor(b1, b2):
    return enot(eor(b1, b2))
#def eand(b1, b2):
#   return enor(enot(b1), enot(b2))
def eand(b1, b2):
    ni = getvar()
    print('%s = T[%s+%s]' % (ni, b1, b2))
    #return enot(eaddi(ni, 8))
    ni = eaddi(ni, 8)
    print('%s = T["0"+%s]' % (ni, ni))
    return enot(ni)
def exor(b1, b2):
    return enor(enor(enot(b1), enot(b2)), enor(b1, b2))
def eeqt(vi):
    #return array of 10 bits for all 10 possible values of vi. inverted
    res = []
    vi2 = getvar()
    for i in range(10):
        ni = getvar()
        print('%s = T["0"+%s]' % (ni, vi if i == 0 else vi2))
        print('%s = T["1"+%s]' % (vi2, vi if i == 0 else vi2))
        res.append(ni)
    #e.g. res[0] = !(x == 0)
    return res[0:1] + res[1:][::-1]
def edmon(m1, m2):
    #decode m2 using eeqt. create 2 more variables for november and december
    #m1 is already boolean
    m2p = eeqt(m2)
    v11 = eor(m2p[1], enot(m1))
    m2p[1] = eor(m2p[1], m1)
    v12 = eor(m2p[2], enot(m1))
    m2p[2] = eor(m2p[2], m1)
    ret = m2p + [v11, v12]
    #return ret
    return ret[1:10] + ret[0:1] + ret[10:]
def elmon(dmon):
    #given output of edmon, find first day modulo 7. also output inverted!
    #table = [4, 0, 0, 3, 5, 1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 0, 2]
    d0 = eand(eand(dmon[1], dmon[2]), dmon[10])
    d1 = dmon[5]
    d2 = eand(dmon[8], dmon[11])
    d3 = eand(dmon[3], dmon[6])
    d4 = eand(dmon[0], dmon[9])
    d5 = dmon[4]
    d6 = dmon[7]
    return [d0,d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6]
def enotarr(a):
    return [enot(x) for x in a]
def eadd7(v1, v2):
    vals = [[] for _ in range(7)]
    for a in range(7):
        for b in range(7):
            vals[(a+b)%7].append(eand(v1[a], v2[b]))
    return [functools.reduce(eor, a) for a in vals]

def emod7(d2):
    et = eeqt(d2)
    et = enotarr(et)
    et[0] = eor(et[0], et[7])
    et[1] = eor(et[1], et[8])
    et[2] = eor(et[2], et[9])
    return et[0:7]
def e3mod7(d1):
    et = eeqt(d1) # can't optimize because entries are obtained like 0, 9, 8, ... and 1 must be reached
    #d1 < 4. multiply by 3
    #0*3 = 0, 1*3 = 3, 2*3 = 6, 3*3 = 2
    return [enot(et[0]), '"0"', enot(et[3]), enot(et[1]), '"0"', '"0"', enot(et[2])]

def eout(m7):
    m7 = enotarr(m7)
    val = '"1"'
    ni = getvar()
    for x in m7:
        print('%s = T[%s+%s]' % (ni, x, val))
        val = ni
    return eaddi(ni, 9)

def solve(m1, m2, d1, d2):
    mmod7 = elmon(edmon(m1, m2))
    dmod7 = eadd7(emod7(d2), e3mod7(d1))
    res = eadd7(enotarr(mmod7), dmod7)
    res = res[1:] + res[:1]
    return eout(res[::-1])

#print(eaddinv(['A'+str(i) for i in range(7)], ['B'+str(i) for i in range(7)]))

#print('print(' + ', '.join(elmon(edmon('M1', 'M2'))) + ')')
#print('print(' + ', '.join(edmon('M1', 'M2')) + ')')

#print('output =', '['+','.join(e3mod7('d1'))+']')
#print('output =', '['+','.join(eadd7(e3mod7('d1'), emod7('d2')))+']')
#print('output =', '['+','.join(emod7('d2'))+']')
#print('output =', '['+','.join(solve('m1','m2','d1','d2'))+']')
print('output =', solve('m1', 'm2', 'd1', 'd2'))
```

No TIO links because of the code size. The generator can be run as `python3 x.py > solution.py`.

## Explanation

In the table T, `T[0x]` is `0` when x is `0` and `1` otherwise, and `T[1x]` is `(x+1) % 10`.
Then logic can be performed on values in (0, 1):

```
!bit = T['0' + (bit+9)]
b1 | b2 = T['0' + T[b1 + b2]]
```

OR and NOT are functionally complete (and can be used to evaluate any boolean function).
To perform any boolean calculations on the input, it should be converted to bits. In my code, it's done like this:

```
!(x == 0) = T['0' + x]
!(x == 9) = T['0' + (x+1)%10]
!(x == 8) = T['0' + (x+2)%10]
...
!(x == 1) = T['0' + (x+9)%10]
```

(and a 10-bit representation is obtained from this).
To convert a sequence of bits to a number, the following is used in my code:

```
x = 1
x = T[bit1 + x]
x = T[bit2 + x]
x = T[bit3 + x]
...
x = T[bitn + x]
x = x + 9
```

After this, `x` is the number of zeroes after the last `1` in the sequence of bits (modulo 10 and assuming the sequence of bits is short).
In my code, integers modulo 7 are represented as sequences of 7 bits (when the bit at index `i` is set, the integer is equal to `i`). Some calculations are performed with inverted values. Addition is implemented by checking for all 49 possible cases and selecting the correct output.

Comment: I left some comments in the chat room https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/57062225#57062225

Comment: Combined, but with what?

Comment: @Neil With the (64, 4) answer. I see it's been updated now.

Comment: I think your `T0` might be inefficient; inverting it should cut your `B` to about 800 or so. I'm still trying to work out how `eout` would work though, since I can't figure out what it's doing.

Comment: @Neil `eout` inverts bit sequences and converts them to numbers; for example, `0100000` becomes `1011111` and `1011111` becomes `5` (the number of ones after the last zero in `1011111`). It works because `T['0'+almost anything]` is `1` (so the last zero resets the counter to 1, all following `1`s increment it, and 9 is added in the end to output numbers in [0, 6] instead of [1, 7]).

Comment: With inverted `T0` I was able to cut your solution down to `A=20, B=767`.

Comment: (now `A=20, B=751`)

Comment: Swapping `T0` and `T1` gets me down to `A=20, B=734`.

Comment: Optimising `eadd7` gets me down to `A=20,B=487`.

Comment: (I've just realised I've been miscounting, since your last output line is just renaming a variable and therefore doesn't count towards `B`, so decrement all of my `B` numbers please.)

Comment: Further optimising `eadd7` gets me down to `A=20,B=360` (counted correctly).

Comment: @Neil How did you optimize it? (today I thought of an easy way to add 3-bit numbers modulo 7, but I couldn't think of anything for adding integers encoded like mine)

Comment: The optimisation is due to the "or" operation becoming inefficient after inverting `T0` and swapping it with `T1`, in particular there were a lot of double negations going on.

Comment: I'm sure there's still scope for further reductions, but not at a high enough level to encode within the generator, so I've appended my final version of the generator to my answer.